# How to find missing obj and log them?

Tags: javascript

I'm looping over some data but I sometimes not every state is in the `dictionary`, how can I get the list of all those missing states?

```
const result = data.map(function(item) {
  const ditem = dictionary.find(d => d.state == item.state);
  if(ditem) {
    return {
      ...item,
      "lat": ditem.lat ,
      "long": ditem.long
    }
  }
  return item;

});

$("pre").html(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: you could have an array with all needed `states` and for example add `1` whenever you process one... at the end, all the ones with `0` should be logged out...

Comment: can you post some sample data

Comment: @developer sure there you go https://jsfiddle.net/bL43g7sc/2/

Comment: @developer basically I don't understand why I'm missing some states since I get the coords from here https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/states_csv

thought there would be all of them

Comment: here's your missing data https://pastebin.com/zpX2b10c - all entries with your `item` were not found as a state in your `dictionary` ...

Comment: @balexandre any idea why they are missing from here? https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/states_csv

Comment: @rob.m sure... your `data` also contains insular areas, such as Guam `GU` or American Samoa `AS` and your `dictionary` only contains states... here's a [full list in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations#Table)

Comment: @balexandre yes got it eventually, drove me mad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list missing states using `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
const missingStates = data.filter(
    dataItem => !dictionary.some(dictionaryItem => dictionaryItem.state === dataItem.state)
);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212254/discussion-on-answer-by-robo-robok-how-to-find-missing-obj-and-log-them).

Answer (score 1):

```
let missingStates = []; //to store missingStates

const result = data.map(function(item) {
  const ditem = dictionary.find(d => d.state == item.state);
  if(ditem) {
    return {
      ...item,
      "lat": ditem.lat ,
      "long": ditem.long
    }
  }
  missingStates.every(e=>e!=item) && missingStates.push(item) //You can push them over here
  return item;

});

console.log(missingStates) //this will log out all missingStates;

$("pre").html(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: to avoid duplicates I would check if the state is already in 

Comment: thanks, resolved it jsfiddle.net/tx5r2ch8 I need to check what they are then, google tells me these are the us states developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/states_csv

Comment: @balexandre if the state is already in function will return before pushing them into array so there wont be any duplicates right?

Comment: depends what you want to log, as I assumed, "I want to see what states I have that were not in that list", then `missingStates.push(item)` will push all, as if you check the `data` content, it has several items with duplicate states, your code would have duplicates... a simple `if (!missingStates.find(d => d.state == item.state)) missingStates.push(item)` would avoid duplication as you are checking if the wrong data was already reported

Comment: I wanted to log the missing ones, basically I wanted to find the names of those states I don't have on https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/states_csv what are my missing states then? Thought would be all the us on there

Comment: @balexandre oh i see let me edit then, thanks for the feedback